# How to change background for cordova app?

Tags: android, css, cordova

I ran into a problem that Xiaomi smartphones have a color scheme that inverts colors. Already used meta with content light and blocked with style css. But the color scheme in the application is not ignored and drop all design.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35949482/cordova-gray-background-color

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.